# How to a specify a specific bootstrap table where there are two or more on the page

Tags: bootstrap-4

The code below is copied from the bootstrap examples but easily demonstrates my problem. I have just started using bootstrap and guess I'm not using good search questions.

I have a page were I have several tables.  This code works great unless I want to add a row - then it creates a row in every table.

How can I modify the code so that when the user clicks on the Add New button, it only adds a row in that table (not all the tables)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap Table with Add and Delete Row Feature</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    color: #404E67;
    background: #F5F7FA;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.table-wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;  
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.table-title {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.table-title h2 {
    margin: 6px 0 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.table-title .add-new {
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.table-title .add-new i {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
table.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
}
table.table th i {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.table th:last-child {
    width: 100px;
}
table.table td a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    min-width: 24px;
}    
table.table td a.add {
    color: #27C46B;
}
table.table td a.edit {
    color: #FFC107;
}
table.table td a.delete {
    color: #E34724;
}
table.table td i {
    font-size: 19px;
}
table.table td a.add i {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}    
table.table .form-control {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
table.table .form-control.error {
    border-color: #f50000;
}
table.table td .add {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("table").append(row);     
        $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if(!empty){
            input.each(function(){
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            });         
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
        }       
    });
    // Edit row on edit button click
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });     
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-lg">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Employee <b>Details</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                        <td>Administration</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Peter Parker</td>
                        <td>Customer Service</td>
                        <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fran Wilson</td>
                        <td>Human Resources</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    


<div class="container-lg">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Customer <b>Details</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Account type</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jasmine Doe</td>
                        <td>Business</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Josephine Franks</td>
                        <td>VIP</td>
                        <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joe Cool</td>
                        <td>Personal</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic question, you should do some tutorials so that you understand the basics.

`$("table")` will get all table elements

`$("#myTable")` will get an element with id `myTable` e.g. `<table id="myTable"></table>`

[jQuery Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquERy/jquery_syntax.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("#myTable tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("#myTable").append(row);     
        $("#myTable tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if(!empty){
            input.each(function(){
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            });         
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
        }       
    });
    // Edit row on edit button click
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });     
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap Table with Add and Delete Row Feature</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    color: #404E67;
    background: #F5F7FA;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.table-wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;  
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.table-title {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.table-title h2 {
    margin: 6px 0 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.table-title .add-new {
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.table-title .add-new i {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
table.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
    border-color: #e9e9e9;
}
table.table th i {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.table th:last-child {
    width: 100px;
}
table.table td a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    min-width: 24px;
}    
table.table td a.add {
    color: #27C46B;
}
table.table td a.edit {
    color: #FFC107;
}
table.table td a.delete {
    color: #E34724;
}
table.table td i {
    font-size: 19px;
}
table.table td a.add i {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}    
table.table .form-control {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
table.table .form-control.error {
    border-color: #f50000;
}
table.table td .add {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-lg">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Employee <b>Details</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                        <td>Administration</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Peter Parker</td>
                        <td>Customer Service</td>
                        <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fran Wilson</td>
                        <td>Human Resources</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    


<div class="container-lg">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Customer <b>Details</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Account type</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jasmine Doe</td>
                        <td>Business</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Josephine Franks</td>
                        <td>VIP</td>
                        <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joe Cool</td>
                        <td>Personal</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I do know that.  What I can't work out is how to modify    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();  to point to #mytable

Comment: Ahh okay. I think what you want to do is replace table with it's respective id, i.e. `$("#myTable tbody tr:last-child").index();`

Comment: I did try that.  But it doesn't work.  It still give me that add option for both tables

Comment: @DaSy I've added a code snippet to my answer, so you can see if you click Add New +, it only adds to the first table

Comment: Thank you! It looks so obvious now, and actually, I thought I had tried that but I must have missed a place where I needed to sub 'mytable' or else I fat-fingered something and thought I was on the wrong path.  Again, thank you!